# IPC::Open3::open3() doesn't work with perl 5.14.2 as with perl 5.10.1?

Tags: perl, ipc, ipcopen3

In one of our modules, we check if a given binary (`varnishd`) exists, and if so, we run additional tests.

To perform the check, we're using `IPC::Open3`, like this (example stripped down for clarity):

```
perl -MIPC::Open3 -le '
    my $binary = "varnishd";
    my $pid = IPC::Open3::open3(my($in, $out), undef, $binary, "-V");
    waitpid $pid, 0; print $?'
```

Under Debian Squeeze, or Ubuntu Natty, with **perl 5.10.1**, if `varnishd` is not found on the system, this prints `65280` for me.
If you change the `$binary` to `perl`, then is (correctly) prints `0`.

However, with Ubuntu Precise and **perl 5.14.2**, this doesn't work in the same way anymore, and produces the following:

```
$ perl -MIPC::Open3 -le '
    my $binary = "varnishd";
    my $pid = IPC::Open3::open3(my($in, $out), undef, $binary, "-V");
    waitpid $pid, 0; print $?'
open3: exec of varnishd -V failed at -e line1
```

When I change the `$binary` to something that exists, for example `perl`, then it works correctly and prints `0`.

```
$ perl -MIPC::Open3 -le '
    my $binary = "perl";
    my $pid = IPC::Open3::open3(my($in, $out), undef, $binary, "-V");
    waitpid $pid, 0; print $?'
0
```

Reading other questions and answers, it looks like I want to look into [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun), but I would like to actually:

- understand this difference of behaviour
- **avoid any more dependencies** if possible

EDIT: forgot to mention that this stuff is running under a **chroot** environment, both Squeeze and Precise systems, if that's at all relevant (`/dev` filesystem differences, for example?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are noticing a [bug](https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72016) [fix](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/8960aa876f446ad29b892204eeb41fc724123dcb).

In what you call the 5.10.1 version, `open3` reported that the program ran and exited with code 255. Neither of those are true.

In what you call the 5.14.2 version, `open3` throws an exception as it has always been documented to do and as it always has done for some other problems. You may catch failures to launch the child using with `eval BLOCK` if so desired.